# Problem when using .Add to a List of char[] in c#

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to solve a little problem that involves taking a string and returning all possible variations of lower and uppercase letters in that string. I will post my code below (please keep in mind i am new to c#) but only a small part of it is relevant, so if you prefer you can skip right to that part.

```
public class Solution {
public IList<string> LetterCasePermutation(string S) {
    char[] charArray = S.ToCharArray();
    List<char[]> solution = new List<char[]>();
    List<string> solution2 = new List<string>();
    solution.Add(charArray);
    solution2.Add(S);
    char [] newArray;
    char test;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < S.Length ; i++){
        if(Char.IsLetter(charArray[i])){
            int lengthsolution = solution.Count();
            for(int j = 0 ; j < lengthsolution; j++){
            Console.WriteLine("Starting for i = "+i+" and j = "+j+" with char = "+charArray[i]+ " "+ lengthsolution);
                newArray = solution2[j].ToCharArray();
                if(Char.IsLower(newArray[i])){
                    newArray[i] = Char.ToUpper(newArray[i]); 
                } else {
                    newArray[i] = Char.ToLower(newArray[i]);
                }
                solution.Add(newArray); 
                string newstring = new string(newArray);
                solution2.Add(newstring);
            }
        }
    }
    return solution2;
}
```

}

This code does indeed work and returns me what i am looking for. The relevant part of the Code is this part:

```
            int lengthsolution = solution.Count();
            for(int j = 0 ; j < lengthsolution; j++){
                newArray = solution2[j].ToCharArray();
                [Here i do some modifications of newArray]
                solution.Add(newArray); 
                string newstring = new string(newArray);
                solution2.Add(newstring);
            }
```

I take an array of chars, do some modifications to it and then add the new char[] to a List of char[]. I also convert the char[9 to a string and add the string to another List of strings. To my understanding those two lists should have the exact same content, just one in form of strings and the other one in char[].

As you may have spotted at the start of the loop i get newArray out of the solution-list and convert it to an array. If the lists are truly identical i should be able to skip any converting and instead of using `newArray = solution2[j].ToCharArray();` i could use `newArray = solution[j];`. However if i do that it changes the output, indicating that `solution` and `solution2` are not identical in content.

For example, with the input: `"a1b2"` I either get:

```
["a1b2","A1b2","a1B2","A1B2"]
```

when using the extra conversion from solution2 or

```
["a1b2","A1b2","A1B2","A1b2"]
```

when using solution (notice the third output has a uppercase A instead of lowercase a)

Any ideas why this is happening and how i can prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
newArray = solution2[j].ToCharArray()
```

you get a *new* char[] array consisting of the characters from the string in `solution2`.

If you just do

```
newArray = solution[j]
```

you do not create a new array. Your variable `newArray` is an additional refernece to the array in `solution[j]`. Any modifications to the elements of `newArray` are also *visible* in `solution[j]`.

You can do

```
newArray = (char[])solution[j].Clone()
```

or with LINQ (`using System.Linq;`)

```
newArray = solution[j].ToArray();
```

to get a new copy of the array.

Comment: So when i modify newarray i am also modifying solutions[j] at the same time?
How can i create a copy of solutions[j] that i can change without changing solution[j]?

Comment: _also modifying_ is the wrong description. An array is a reference type and you just have two variables referencing the _same_ array.

Comment: I tried 'newArray = solutions[j].Clone()' but i get an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'char[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

I think i get what the problem is (that i don't have two distinct variables, but just 2 references to the same object) so i am wondering if i am trying to solve the problem in a way that is not common. How would one usually handle such a task (taking contents of a list and changing it without changing the list itself) in c#?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `(char[])` cast.

Comment: Thanks! The code now works (when removing the s from solutionS, i think you copied my first replied where i made a typo).

I will have to read up a bit about how stuff is stored in C#, thanks for your help!